# React Can't import images in any component

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, reactjs

Starting of with my webpack.config:

---

```
{
   test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
   use:{
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {},
   },
},
```

And in any of my components:

---

```
import img from'../images/test.png';
```

I have no idea why this happens. I've used this loader several times but I've never encountered this problem. The moment I include an ***.png*** image I get the following error message:

> _react-setup/dist/app/images/test.png:1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { �PNG
>                                                                 ^
>
> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

I'm not doing anything crazy atm. Just a small node server, react, react dom and styled-components.

Does anyone know what happens and how to solve it? I also tried to put the images in a different dir but nothing really helped.

Thanks in advance

Full webpack.config

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/client/index.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'dist/public/bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
        ],
        exclude: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
        ],
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          presets: ["es2015", "react", "stage-2"],
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {}
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: Try `import * as img from '../images/test.png';`

Comment: Which version of webpack do you use? Also could you post entire webpack config?

Comment: I'm currently in the train with limited internet. Will come back to you in an hour! Thanks

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I use 3.6 for webpack + posted my whole config file

Comment: @DiederikEenschooten Looks ok to me. Random guess: try to add `include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') ` to the last rule as well :)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko didn't work :/ maybe it's node thats screwing it up?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, let me know if you found the fix.